# How to PREPARE & EXECUTE a query from a string stored in a table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

This stored function returns a query:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_query (
  ctl text, scm text, tbl text, seq text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_query (
  ctl text, scm text, tbl text, seq text)
RETURNS text
AS
$$
    select concat('insert into ',$2,'.',$1, ' select nextval("',$4,'") as id, ',
           string_agg(concat('NEW.', column_name), ', '), ', current_timestamp as audited_at;')
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_catalog = $1
      and table_schema = $2
      and table_name = $3
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

How do I `PREPARE` the query that this function returns.

I want insert a record in a table when a trigger is fired but I don't want to specify the list of columns to be inserted. The schema might keep changing. Hence, trying to use prepared statements.

This sample code illustrates how I mean the query string to be executed:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_name (store_temporary_query text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name (store_temporary_query text)
RETURNS table (query text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    begin

        select 'select 1 as ID' into store_temporary_query;
        return query (select store_temporary_query);

    end;
$$

select fn_name('');
```

The above query gives the following output

```
fn_name
select 1 as ID
```

The desired result is the query

```
ID
1
```

**EDIT #2**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_name (store_temporary_query text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_name (store_temporary_query text)
RETURNS table (query text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
    begin

        select 'select 1 as ID;' into store_temporary_query;
        return query execute store_temporary_query;

    end;
$$

select fn_name('');
```

This gets us here,

```
Error executing SQL statement. ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
  Position: 254 - Connection: Aurora Legacy: 794ms
```

Comment: Use PL/pgSQL's `EXECUTE`?

Comment: Don't know how to `PREPARE` a statement from a query stored in a table.

Comment: `PREPARE` is for prepared statements, which only makes sense if you want to execute the statement multiple times. Could you flesh out your use case some more so that I understand it better?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I am storing a query in a table. I want to be able to execute that query somehow from a Trigger.

Comment: And what should happen with the query results?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I have made an EDIT to the question. I think that will clarity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188043/discussion-between-montypython-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 0):

You need `EXECUTE` to execute a query stored in a string:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE store_temporary_query;
```

Comment: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select". It's because it is not a `PREPARED` statement, right?

Comment: I repeat, this has nothing to do with prepared statements. On the contrary, this is dynamic SQL. When I execute your function, I get `ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Returned type integer does not match expected type text in column 1.` That's because you declared the result column `query` as `text` instead of `integer`. If you get some other error, maybe you are not using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. Now it is returning an int. But it still gets the same error as before - Error executing SQL statement. ERROR: syntax error at or near "select". I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: All I can say is it works here. It would be good to have the context information; where exactly the problem is. Can you run it from `psql`?